# Using Fusion Tables tiles in Leaflet.js or on non-Google map base?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, openstreetmap, google-fusion-tables, leaflet

I love the fact that Google Fusion Tables can show many thousands of markers on a map efficiently.

My question: is it possible (both technically and legally) to display a [Fusion Tables layer](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-fusiontables-simple) on top of OpenStreetMap map tiles, in either of the following scenarios:

1. Using [Leaflet.js](http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/) with OSM tiles and a Fusion Tables layer. I'm not sure if this is technically possible, let alone legally.
2. Using the Google Maps API with a [Fusion Tables layer](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-fusiontables-simple) and [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) tiles. Technically this is clearly possible, but I'm not sure whether Fusion Tables results have to be displayed on Google map tiles (like Google geocoder results do).

I can't see anything in the [Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/terms) that specifically rules out non-Google map tiles. My preferred option would be Leaflet, but I don't know if there's a way to call the Fusion Tables layer using Leaflet.

NB: I'm not talking about making JSON queries to Fusion Tables and rendering individual markers, I'm specifically talking about the tile layer that lets you show many thousands of markers without having to render them individually.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

@flossfan, check out [CartoDB.com](http://www.CartoDB.com). You get a nice SQL API for dynamic table and tile queries, plus really nice styling options. You can use it with OSM or any other base map (including Google Maps). They've actually got a CartoDB-Leaflet library too:

https://github.com/Vizzuality/cartodb-leaflet

This comparison of CartoDB and Fusion Tables (from the folks making CartoDB) includes a demo displaying lots of points:

http://blog.cartodb.com/post/21264086445/comparing-fusion-tables-to-open-source-cartodb

If you don't need the dynamic queries and styling that CartoDB offers, check out [MapBox.com](http://www.mapbox.com) and TileMill. You can design really beautiful maps using as many points as you like, then bake them into static map tiles. This demo shows lots of points:

http://tiles.mapbox.com/dhcole/map/dots-and-lines

Both CartoDB and TileMill are open source, and they're great to have in your mapping toolbox.

I'm sure that between Fusion Tables, CartoDB and TileMill you'll find some way to display your data!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no documented access to Fusion Tables tiles, so according to [Section 10.1 of the Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_1):

> You must not access or use the Maps API(s) or any Content through any technology or means other than those provided in the Service, or through other explicitly authorized means Google may designate. For example, you must not access map tiles or imagery through interfaces or channels (including undocumented Google interfaces) other than the Maps API(s).

Furthermore, `FusionTablesLayer` is more than just for display: it also provides click events. I'd definitely recommend you use the Google Maps Javascript API to display a `FusionTablesLayer`.